# Repetition Issues with Query

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

So I am having a repeating issue with one of my reports.
I am currently running this query through Microsoft Sql Server 2012.
Here is what I am working with:

```
SELECT 
  oh.ORDERNO,
  od.Rxnum,
  oh.STATUS,
  datediff(hh, o.recvtime, getdate()) as ageInHours

FROM
  mck_hvs.ORDERHEADER oh with (nolock),
  mck_hvs.ORDERDETAILS od with (nolock),
  mck_hvs.SCRIPTITEMS si with (nolock),
  mck_hvs.orderheader o with(nolock)

WHERE
  oh.orderno = od.orderno and
  si.orderno = od.orderno and
  oh.STATUS = 550 and
  od.DrugClass = 'C2' and
  datediff(hh, o.recvtime, getdate()) <24

ORDER BY
  oh.STATUS,
  oh.orderno,
  od.rxnum,
  datediff(hh, o.recvtime, getdate()) desc
```

I am trying to get a report to list out specific order numbers for my pharmacy, and it will list them off, but there can be anywhere from 20-30 pages of the same order number information.

Comment: I will guess that your joins are resulting in more rows than you desire.  Perhaps add one table at a time and use modern join syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, this is how SQL works: a header (as in the OrderHeader) is repeated for each matching Detail (as in OrderDetails). You might need extra processing (possibly in another language - tool) to achieve "better" format of the report.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are doing a self-join between two copies of the Orderheader table without a join condition. Whenever you do a join without a join condition you get every combination of the tables you join. In this case if you have 1000 rows in the Orderheader table this one join will give you 1,000,000 rows in the answer. I would recommend that you use the "join" syntax in SQL. This makes it clearer what the join conditions are. If you want Orderheaders in your results even if you do not have a matching orderdetails or scriptitems, then you will need to change the join for that table to a left join. Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    oh.ORDERNO,
    od.Rxnum,
    oh.STATUS,
    datediff(hh, o.recvtime, getdate()) as ageInHours
FROM
    mck_hvs.ORDERHEADER as oh inner join 
    mck_hvs.ORDERDETAILS as od on oh.orderno = od.orderno inner join
    mck_hvs.SCRIPTITEMS as si on si.orderno = od.orderno inner join
    mck_hvs.orderheader as o on <<MISSING JOIN CONDITION GOES HERE>>
WHERE
    oh.STATUS = 550 and
    od.DrugClass = 'C2' and
    datediff(hh, o.recvtime, getdate()) <24
ORDER BY
    oh.STATUS,
    oh.orderno,
    od.rxnum,
    datediff(hh, o.recvtime, getdate()) desc
```